# XSLT to remove some attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML which can appear in either form in my XML Document:

`<Message xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.location.com StructureFile.xsd" xmlns=http://www.thenamespace.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`

or

`<Message xmlns="http://www.thenamespace.com">`

and I need the output to be:

`<Message xmlns="http://www.theNEWnamespace.com">`

I currently have this template to handle the shorter version of the two xml possibilities:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="http://www.theNEWnamespace.com">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

However this does not remove the SchemeLocation or xmlns:xsi parts of the xml if they are in existance.

How would I go about adapting the above to handle both possibilities.

Cheers,

Edit: XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Message xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.location.com StructureFile.xsd" xmlns="http://www.thenamespace.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header>
    <Info></Info>
  </Header>
</Message>
```

Comment: The XML document that you have provided has a different default namespace than the one you specify at the start of this question. Please, correct.

Comment: Another issue is that the names of the attribute are different: `"xsi:schemaLocation"` and `"xsi:SchemaLocation"` -- please correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here is a complete transformation producing the wanted result**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.thenamespace.com">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="x:Message">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="http://www.theNEWnamespace.com">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name() = 'xsi:SchemaLocation')]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (none provided!):

```
<t>
  <Message
  xsi:SchemaLocation="http://www.location.com StructureFile.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.thenamespace.com"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Message xmlns="http://www.theNEWnamespace.com"/>
```

Comment: Added the structure incase it makes a change required, currently doesnt seem to work so assume the structure probably omitted something.

Comment: @Mike: In your provided XML the default namespace is different. Change it in my solution: from `"http://www.thenamespace.com"` to `"http://www.thenamespace"` -- or better correct your question, wich uses both namespaces and is contradictory.

Comment: @Mike: There is also mismatch between the attribute names -- please correct, then my solution will work for you.

Comment: Corrected and it works, sorry for the typos causing said error!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in the XSLT/XPath data model only the `xsi:schemaLocation` is an attribute. If you don't want to copy that attribute or any attributes at all, well, then don't do `<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>` because there you explicitly copy all attributes. Or if you want to selectively specify which attributes not to copy then instead of the `<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>` put in `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>`, then write one template for copying attributes and then templates for those attributes you don't want to copy e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@xsi:schemaLocation"/>
```

As for `xmlns:xsi`, that is a namespace declaration which in the XSLT/XPath data model is not an attribute. And if all you do for element nodes is the template you have shown then I don't see how that namespace should be copied through to the output.

If you however define namespaces in the stylesheet too then you need `exclude-result-prefixes="xsi"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: The namespace node is *necessary* because the attribute belongs to this namespace. It has to be created by the XSLT processor, because the generic template matching all elements doesn't copy namespace nodes.

Comment: You are right, Dimitre, with his code copying all attributes he will get namespace declarations for any namespaces attributes are in. But if Mike doesn't want the attribute(s) and follows one of my suggestions not to copy them then his template for elements doing `xsl:element` won't result in any namespace declaration of unused namespaces.

Comment: Exactly -- this is why my answer produces the wanted result.